# Authorize.NET iOS transaction won't process if > 999

Tags: ios, objective-c, authorize.net

I'm using iOS 7 with the Authorize.NET iOs library and I can't get transactions over 999 to process. Doesn't anyone have a clue why? I've tried several different ways of formatting. I don't get any error other than processing failed.

```
    TransactionRequestType *requestType = [TransactionRequestType transactionRequest];
requestType.lineItems = lineItems;


requestType.amount  =  [[authNetNumFmt stringFromNumber:_total]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$"   withString:@""];
requestType.amount  =  [[authNetNumFmt stringFromNumber:_total]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@","   withString:@""];


requestType.payment = paymentType;

// Required for card present transactions.
requestType.retail = [TransRetailInfoType transRetailInfoType];
requestType.retail.marketType = MARKET_TYPE_RETAIL;
requestType.retail.deviceType = DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN;

CreateTransactionRequest *request = [CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest];
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.name = sessionManager.authNetLoginId;  
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = sessionManager.authNetTransactionKey;  
request.transactionRequest = requestType;
request.transactionType = AUTH_CAPTURE;

[authNetInstance purchaseWithRequest:request]; //pass with 999 but fail with 1000
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be referred to Authorize.net support

Comment: Authorize basically said it has something to do with the way the API is being called. The amounts if I print them out are "999" and "1000" respectively so there just aren't any special characters in the amount field. I don't know what else to check.

Comment: Does your merchant account have a limit of <$1000 ?

Comment: not according to Authorize.net... but I'm not sure their support was knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be simple. The LineItems had prices in there that exceeded $1000 and the conversion to String had made it 1,000 which caused the XML to be invalid since the XML schema said it must be a number. I just have to remove special characters from the price as well as the total and it worked.